# Error Running Selenium/Django/Firefox. unable to create file '/var/www/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly

Tags: django, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium 4.1 with geckodriver 0.32.2 and firefox 110.0.1. The AWS EC2 is on Ubuntu 22.04. I had to install firefox not using snap.

Here is the code to get the driver.

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
if not driver:
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Here is the error in the geckodriver log.

```
1678369806282   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:57825
1678369806786   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "50887" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileq2trdx"
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt

(firefox:18279): dconf-CRITICAL **: 13:51:06.828: unable to create file '/var/www/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

I have given 777 permission to the folder and everything.

It then fails in the code for the following stacktrace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ondefend/Blindspot/./apps/universal/decorators.py", line 57, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ondefend/Blindspot/./apps/react/views/reporting_views.py", line 678, in download_report
    report.make_charts_react(f'http://'+request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
  File "/opt/ondefend/Blindspot/./apps/reporting/models.py", line 667, in make_charts_react
    screenshot.screenshot_charts_react(self.project, f'media/reports/{self.customer.name}/{self.name}/')
  File "/opt/ondefend/Blindspot/./apps/reporting/screenshot.py", line 75, in screenshot_charts_react
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 179, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port
```